# Installing time zone data on MariaDB 10.0

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux, centos, timezone

Yesterday, I set the time zone on our DB server (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686965/114558)).  Doing so required using the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` executable.  Fortunately, this already existed on the server, and conversion of the time zone data went smoothly.

However, today I can see that our slave is generating the same error.  The problem is that the slave doesn't seem to have the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` executable.  `apt-get` tells me that it exists in these other packages:

```
root@slave:~# mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/|mysql -u root mysql
The program 'mysql_tzinfo_to_sql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-server-5.5
 * mariadb-server-5.5
 * mysql-server-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

I'm concerned that installing one of these (probably would choose `mariadb-server-5.5`) would conflict with our currently-installed version of MariaDB (10.0.17-MariaDB-1~precise-log).

**How should I go about installing this time zone data on the slave?**

- Can it be easily copied over from the master's DB?
- Is my concern about installing `mariadb-server-5.5` unwarranted?
- Is there a totally different approach I'm missing?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: CentOS... 7, I think?

Comment: No, I think you were on Ubuntu Precise. Lol

Comment: Ah, I just re-read the question (it has been a while... :) ) Yes, this was on our slave, so likely Ubuntu. Not Precise, but something recent-ish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  The key to this solution is that I already had a system (the master) that I knew I could generate the timezone SQL on.  I simply generated the SQL on the master, transferred it to the slave, and executed it!

**On Master**

```
user@master [~]# mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ > timezones.sql
```

**On Slave**

```
root@slave:~# scp -P2223 user@master:timezones.sql .
user@master's password: 
stdin: is not a tty
timezones.sql                                                                                                                                   100% 4562KB   2.2MB/s   00:02    
root@slave:~# cat timezones.sql | mysql -u root mysql
```

After executing `START SLAVE` on the slave, everything worked great!

Still curious if someone has answers to the questions I posed originally, though!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm concerned that installing one of these (probably would choose mariadb-server-5.5) would conflict with our currently-installed version of MariaDB (`10.0.17-MariaDB-1~`**`precise`**`-log`).

Ubuntu Precise was released 12.04. It's super ridiculous old, and it was when you asked the question. That's why the version of MariaDB was so old too. [MariaDB dropped support for precise in 10.0.31.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-10031-release-notes/) Because you're running on an unofficial in Debian/Ubuntu's eyes version of MariaDB, it's not guaranteed to work with the system.

All of that said, the question is essentially who packaged your MariaDB. It seems likely you got it from [MariaDB](http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/mariadb//mariadb-10.0.31/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.0/) upstream. So while you have a workaround, the question is better phrased like this

- Where does MariaDB install `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql`?

Clearly it's not in your path, you can find it by

1. running the package you downloaded through `dpkg -c`.
2. using `apt-file`
3. Running: `sudo updatedb; locate mysql_tzinfo_to_sql;`

Comment: Thank you! Busy working on other things right now, but if this pops up again, I'll give it a go! :)